# Create multiple DIVs and assign unique ID

Tags: javascript, arrays, createelement

I am trying to create multiple divs and assign them a unique ID with javascript, preferably the name of a state as it's printed in the console log. Nothing I try works though. Any advice? I have followed every similar question and answer I can find on this forum but nothing works for my situation.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Untitled Document</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <div id="myDiv">
        </div>
        
        <script>
    
            getData(); //call function
            
            async function getData(){ //define an asynchronous function

                var response = await fetch('covid.csv'); //call data and assign it to a variable
                var data = await response.text(); //parse the text from the response and assign it to variable    
                console.log(data);
                
                var table = data.split('\n').slice(1, -1); //delineate rows of the table by splitting them at the line break. This results in an array such as: [0] Alaska, 12, 1.33 etc
                console.log(table);

                table.forEach(row => {
                    var columns = row.split(','); 
                    var state = columns[0];
                    var deaths = columns[1];
                    var deathsPer = columns[2];
                    console.log(state, deaths, deathsPer);
                             
                  /*
                  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = //DOESN'T WORK need to create new div for each row
                    state + 
                    " death toll is " + 
                    deaths + 
                    " and a death rate of " + 
                    deathsPer
                    ;
                   */

                    for(var i=0;i<50;i++){   //DOESN'T WORK creates 50 divs x50
                    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
                    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
                    newDiv.setAttribute("id", 'textBar' + i);
                    }
                                                                 
                });
            }
                        
        </script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The attributes of elements are accessible as properties of their objects. This means you can just use `newDiv.id = 'textBar' + i;` to assign the ID.

Comment: You should also probably remove the for-loop (but keep it's content) since you are creating 50 `div`'s per row.

Comment: thanks but then it doesn't do anything... it just creates one div that's the problem. any idea how to get it to iterate for each row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already looping with your `forEach`, so no need for the extra loop. And inside that extra loop, you were not setting the innerHML:

**ES6 version**

```js
const $myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

(async function getData() {
  // Just for the demo
  const data = '\nVirginia,12,1\nCalifornia,24,3\nFlorida,36,11\n';
  const table = data.split('\n').slice(1, -1);
  
  table.forEach(row => {
    const [ state, deaths, deathsPer ] = row.split(','),
      $newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      
    $newDiv.innerHTML = `${state} death toll is ${deaths}
                         and a death rate of ${deathsPer}`;
    $newDiv.id = `textBar_${state}`;
    $myDiv.appendChild($newDiv);
  });
})();
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

**An easier to understand version** (only with the ES6 features you were already using)

```js
const $myDiv = document.getElementById('myDiv');

getData();

async function getData() {
  // Just for the demo
  const data  = '\nVirginia,12,1\nCalifornia,24,3\nFlorida,36,11\n',
        table = data.split('\n').slice(1, -1);
  
  table.forEach(row => {
    const columns   = row.split(','),
          state     = columns[0],
          deaths    = columns[1],
          deathsPer = columns[2],
          $newDiv   = document.createElement("div");
      
    $newDiv.innerHTML = state + " death toll is " + deaths
                      + " and a death rate of " + deathsPer;
                      
    $newDiv.id = "textBar_" + state;
    $myDiv.appendChild($newDiv);
  });
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the way you wrote this is beyond my ability to understand, is that ecma script? I'm still learning javascript and only understand it in its most basic form, I haven't learned ecma yet. I'll work on implementing it though.

Comment: oh wow it worked! thank you! I'm following youtube videos and haven't learned how to use the $ symbol or know why you used it, I'll work on it though.

Comment: Ok, sorry, I added a simpler version. The strings with `${}` inside them are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and I added a `$` in the name of the variables that contain DOM elements (HTML) just as a convention, so that I instantly know what this variable contains when reading the code. That's not a requirement

Comment: Yes thanks again! I'm not sure if I should start another question for this, but I had been using deathsPer.toFixed(2) previously in order to round the digit to 2 decimal places, but now the console is giving me an error and says "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: deathsPer.toFixed is not a function" Any idea why that would be happening now?

Comment: When you split the row's string, you end up with strings, and those don't have a `toFixed` method. You need to convert them to numbers: `const deathsPer = parseFloat(columns[2]);` Then you can use `deathsPer.toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is because the if of the the div you're creating are not unique because you are creating first time textBar1..textBar50 and the secondo circle of forEach you're creating the same id on the div.

Try to add an index to the forach like this: `table.forEach((row, id) => {` and on the line where you set the attribute make something like this:

newDiv.setAttribute("id", `textBar-${id} - ${i}` );